# Find and replace text between ##

Tags: mysql, sql

I have lot of records like this in table p_suppliers

```
www.loohuis.nl#http://www.loohuis.nl#
```

which I want to have like this

```
www.loohuis.nl
```

why is this query not working?

```
UPDATE p_suppliers set site = REPLACE(site, '#%#','') ;
```

Comment: Are you looking to remove the 2nd URL, after the first '#' ?

Comment: Hi Radu, unfortunately is also not working

Comment: Your query is not working because `REPLACE()` is not `LIKE`.  It does not accept wildcards.

Comment: the used database is mysql

Comment: thanks Gordon i did not know that, but without wildcards it is not working eather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
DECLARE @OpenTag varchar(10)
SET @OpenTag = '#'

UPDATE p_suppliers
SET site= STUFF(site,
                       CHARINDEX(@OpenTag, site,1)  + LEN(@OpenTag),
                            CHARINDEX('#',site,1)-(CHARINDEX(@OpenTag, site,1)  + LEN(@OpenTag)), 
                       '')
```